# Clang - difference between Windows snapshot build and release 3.7.1

Tags: c++, windows, clang, llvm

What's the difference between LLVM toolchain from there http://llvm.org/builds/ (Windows snapshot build, 32 and 64-bit) and there http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.7.1 (Clang for Windows 3.7.1, 32 and 64-bit)? What's better to choose for Windows 7 64-bit, the former or the latter (with MinGW 64-bit)?

Also, why the former has version 3.9.0, while the latter only 3.7.1? Does the former use newer, better version of Clang than the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snapshot build is something generated by an automated build process,
typically invoked by some source code change, where the resulting snapshot build is typically exercised by a set of so-called regression tests to assess said changes.  Specifically, a snapshot build is
intended to give useful (quick) feedback to developers.

Release builds are made only after achieving all goals for a release cycle. Releases will have been exercised in more (if not all) supported environments, typically after a beta cycle where advanced users report corner-case bugs and otherwise give feedback.

As described in 3.7 release notes, Windows 7 will the 3.9 release minimum requirement.  http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

Release 3.9 will presumably improve on release 3.8, which is not yet generally available.  Asking these questions indicates that a snapshot release would be inappropriate for you.  Stick with supported releases, in this case 3.7.1.